# Javascript: event object reference

Tags: javascript, scope

I am currently fiddling around with the creation of a "pure js-page" (no HTML content no CSS just JSON feeding a "constructor") and stumbled upon a problem I am unable to solve regarding what I believe concerns the scope of a function?!

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
'use strict'
var x = class {
 constructor(args) {
  console.log('class')
  this.a = args[0]
  this.b = args[1]
  this.c = args[2]
  this.d = this.d.bind(this)
  this.e = this.e.bind(this)
  this.d()
 }
}
x.prototype.d = function() {
 console.log('listener')
 document.getElementById('h').addEventListener('mouseover',this.e,false)
}
x.prototype.e = function() {
 console.log('handler')
 this.a(this.b)
}
var f = function(args) {
 console.log('call: '+args)
 console.log(event.target)
}
var g = function(args) {
 new x(args)
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="g([f,'hello',1000]);">
<div id="h" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:grey;">lorem...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

While the above code perfectly executes as "intended" (I don't need to pass the event object separately), I fail to implement setTimeout where the event object is being passed on.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
'use strict'
var x = class {
 constructor(args) {
  console.log('class')
  this.a = args[0]
  this.b = args[1]
  this.c = args[2]
  this.d = this.d.bind(this)
  this.e = this.e.bind(this)
  this.d()
 }
}
x.prototype.d = function() {
 console.log('listener')
 document.getElementById('h').addEventListener('mouseover',this.e,false)
}
x.prototype.e = function() {
 console.log('handler')
 setTimeout(() => {this.a(this.b)},this.c)
}
var f = function(args) {
 console.log('call: '+args)
 console.log(event.target)
}
var g = function(args) {
 new x(args)
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="g([f,'hello',1000]);">
<div id="h" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:grey;">lorem...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The arrow function luckily gets rid of the complete reference nonsense concerning this, but I loose the event reference in "function f".

Is there any way to achieve the same "state" as in the upper example?

Any help is greatly appreciated, but please be aware I am an amateur (yes I did "google") and after hours of reading through scopes, apply, bind, call, arrow functions (I was hoping they would help,... well) and other stuff, I still fail to find a proper solution (!jquery && !node && !angular && !typescript && vanilla).

Greetings

Comment: Function `f` does not know what `event` is. Your first snippet is working in Chrome, but not in FireFox. Don't rely on some browser magic. It is standard thing to specify the `event` as the argument on your callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't pass the event argument `this.a(e, this.b)}`. See the updated snippet:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
'use strict'
var x = class {
 constructor(args) {
  console.log('class')
  this.a = args[0]
  this.b = args[1]
  this.c = args[2]
  this.d = this.d.bind(this)
  this.e = this.e.bind(this)
  this.d()
 }
}
x.prototype.d = function() {
 console.log('listener')
 document.getElementById('h').addEventListener('mouseover',this.e,false)
}
x.prototype.e = function(e) {
 console.log('handler')
 setTimeout(() => {this.a(e, this.b)},this.c)
}
var f = function(event, args) {
 console.log('call: '+args)
 console.log(event.target)
}
var g = function(args) {
 new x(args)
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="g([f,'hello',1000]);">
<div id="h" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:grey;">lorem...</div>
</body>
</html>
```